# Java Schedule a task for single execution

Tags: java, web, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a task in the future, just once.
Requirements:
- The environment is clustered, so need to take care of competition in the moment that the task gets fired, it cannot execute twice;
- The task can be scheduled a month ahead and cannot be just scheduled in memory as soon as the node can be restarted or even destroyed at a certain moments (it's an Amazon Elastick Beanstalk environment);

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: save you task time and other details in database. I would recommend you go through JMS Scheduling

Comment: We end up using Amazon queues (SQS) to guarantee the execution just one time. When one process read a message from the queue it becomes invisible to the others.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: Instead of trying to get the cron/timer tool to only execute once, you could schedule the task on all of the nodes, but then use some kind of coordination between nodes to decide which one will actually execute the task.